# Is this the right way to execute some PHP in my plugin after a button click on an options page?

Tags: plugins, admin

I have an options page for my plugin. I want the user to be able to click a button to execute a member function of my plugin's class. I found this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597846/wordpress-plugin-call-function-on-button-click-in-admin-panel

But I'm not sure if I am interpreting the instructions correctly. I found that creating a form with an action="options-general.php?page=MY_OPTIONS_PAGE_SLUG" will work. Like this:

```
            <form method="post" action="options-general.php?page=my_options_page_slug">
                <input type="hidden" name="banana" value="yellow">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Go') ?>" />
            </form>
```

Is this what the stackoverflow article is recommending? Is this a decent way to do this? I am not  ready to step into (the WP) AJAX just yet. I'm ok with a form and a page refresh.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Its not the safest way to do it but the processing code is missing so i can't really say, post the rest of you code.

Comment: On the other side, I have something simple right now like `if( $_POST['banana'] == 'yellow' ){ $this->do_something(); }`. Will adding a nonce make this method reliable? I am still not sure if the link I provided in the OP meant something like this with the language, "POST that form to your plugin."

Answer (score 1):

Try using ['init'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) action hook to handle the submit trigger. Create a new object of your class in the hooked function and call the member function.

Comment: Hooking into `init` would check the $_POST for my variable on every single page load, even for logged out users. Why would I want that?

Comment: Add a conditional check so that the function runs only on your plugins options page only. `is_admin` should help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that method *should* be fine. Adding a nonce is always a positive thing to do as well.

**From the [WP Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces):** *Nonces are used as a security related protection to prevent attacks and mistakes.* (Sounds good to me!)

You could also use `$pagenow` and `$typenow` variables in place of hardcoding a URL into the form's action attribute.

There are better ways (like AJAX) but I would think this is the "traditional" way to do it.

Comment: I added a nonce last night. Thanks for the tips on these variables. I'll look them up.